# How to read a file path from input in C++ so you can open a txt file?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, iostream, istream

I have a file named myPoints.txt in `c:\\....\mydocuments`. It contains a list of a few x,y points(eg, 3.4,5.6 ).
I'm trying to open it using ifstream. 
As soon as I enter the file directory I get a runtime error and the program closes.(eg...`c:\mydocuments\myPoints.txt`)

1. How do I input the correct file dir?
2. Is there a clean way to put this code into a function with "ifstream ifs" as a parameter??

Here is my file opening code:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter the file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ifs(name.c_str());
    if (!ifs) error("can't open input file ", name);

    vector < Point > points;
    Point p;
    while (ifs >> p) points.push_back(p);
    // ....
}
```

Not sure if the problem is in my ifstream function so I'll add it just in case:

```
ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& ifs, Point& p)
{
    double x, y;
    char comma;
    ifs >> x >> comma >> y;
    if (!ifs) return ifs;
    if (comma != ',') {
        ifs.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return ifs;
    }
    p = Point(x, y);
    return ifs;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the problem is in my ifstream function so I'll add it just in case:ifstream & operator>>(ifstream & ifs, Point & p)
{
double x, y;
char comma;
ifs>>x>>comma>>y;

if(!ifs)
 return ifs;

if(comma != ',')
 {
 ifs.clear(ios_base::failbit);
 return ifs;
 } 
p = Point(x,y);
return ifs;
}

Comment: Yes, you can enter a full path to the file. The main thing is that you need to type it all in correctly (e.g., at least in most locales, you need a space in `My Documents`). Also note that `cin >> name;` will only read up to the first white-space character. You probably want `std::getline(cin, name);`, so it'll read an entire line.

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit it into the question.

Comment: Try using forward slash, '/', instead of backslash, '\'.  Works on *nix and Windows platforms.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That comment of yours is an answer. I think you should make it one.

Comment: Since you could run the program it would be helpful to see the actual output, in particular the file name produced by `if (!ifs) error("can't open input file ", name);`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enter a full path to the file. The main thing is that you need to type it all in correctly (e.g., at least in most locales, you need a space in `My Documents`).

Also note that code like `cin >> name;` (where `name` is a `std::string`) will only read up to the first white-space character. You probably want `std::getline(std::cin, name);` instead, so it'll read an entire line (i.e., everything you type in until a carriage return).